# Getting TypeError during string formattion

Tags: python

```
key=12
head=851
file_pdf='pdf'

s=new_folder+'/'+file_pdf+'/'+'%s-%s.'+file_pdf+'heu'%(str(key),str(head),)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What is wrong in this? Why am I getting a string formatting error. I have given two arguments and two format specifiers. I did everything passed it without a tuple but still not working.

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below for a better way to construct file paths using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

For the immediate problem, the 2 arguments in the tuple are associated with the last string `'heu'` only. This is because `%` has higher operator precedence than does `+`. Because there are no format specifiers in `'heu'` you get the error:

```
key=12
head=851
file_pdf='pdf'

>>> 'heu' % (str(key), str(head),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

You need to make sure that the other components of your string are evaluated before the interpolation occurs. You can do that with parentheses:

```
>>> s = (new_folder + '/' +file_pdf + '/' + '%s-%s.' + file_pdf + 'heu') % (str(key), str(head),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'new_folder' is not defined
```

So `new_folder` is not specified:

```
>>> new_folder = 'blah'
>>> s = (new_folder + '/' +file_pdf + '/' + '%s-%s.' + file_pdf + 'heu') % (str(key), str(head),)
>>> print(s)
blah/pdf/12-851.pdfheu
```

Or you can apply the tuple directly to required string:

```
>>> s = new_folder + '/' +file_pdf + '/' + '%s-%s.' % (str(key), str(head),) + file_pdf + 'heu'
```

---

Now, considering what you are actually trying to do, you might be better off using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to put the pieces together:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> s = os.path.join(new_folder, file_pdf, '%s-%s.%sheu' % (key, head, file_pdf))
>>> print(s)
blah/pdf/12-851.pdfheu
```